# Getting error when executing a lambda function - Parameter \"userId\" has value with no field set

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-aurora-serverless

I guess I am making a silly coding mistake, but have been trying for more than a day. I am trying to insert records onto aurora table with the parameters received as a stream from dynamodb table.

I cant seem to set the parameters on the params object correctly. I want the sql statement and the parameters on the params object to be set outside params as the right statement depends on if it is an INSERT, MODIFY or REMOVE.  Here is my code -

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var RDS = new AWS.RDSDataService();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    var userId;
    var givenName;
    
    const params = {
        secretArn: 'secretArn',
        resourceArn: 'resourceArn',
        database: 'db',
        parameters: [{
                name: 'userId',
                value: {
                    "stringValue": this.userId
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'givenName',
                value: {
                    "stringValue": this.givenName
                }
            }
        ]
    };    
    let record = event['Records'];        
    if (record[0].eventName == 'INSERT') {
        params.sql = `INSERT INTO Users (UserId, GivenName) VALUES(userId, givenName);`
        userId = record[0].dynamodb.NewImage.pk.S;
        givenName = record[0].dynamodb.NewImage.sk.S;            
    }
    let result = await RDS.executeStatement(params).promise();
    return JSON.stringify(result);
};
```

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at examples in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html), you need to prefix the parameter placeholders with `:`. Like this:

```
 params.sql = `INSERT INTO Users (UserId, GivenName) VALUES(:userId, :givenName);`
```

Comment: Thankyou Mark. I believe that could be the issue. I fixed it with what you mentioned. Now I am getting another error "Missing required key 'sql' in params". Why do I get this even though I got it initialized inside of the If statement.

Comment: Are you sure `eventName == 'INSERT'` is true? What does your code do when that isn't true?

Comment: Okay, that is so strange, even though I am inserting an item onto the dynamodb table, it is streaming that event as a REMOVE. It is not getting into that if statement. Thanks Mark. I will close this post.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you are updating an existing record, which is why it is triggering that in the stream perhaps? In general though, your code is broken if it receives something other than an `INSERT` so you should add some code to handle that case.

Comment: Yes definitely have plans to do more if statements